# How to turn the following code in Kinteic.js into a function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, canvas, kineticjs

I have this code, that draws a rounded corner hex, and zooms in and out when moused over and out of it. How can make the code modular and reusable, how can I turn it into a function? Specially the hex drawing codes?

```
    <script src="js/kinetic.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
        function zoomHex() {
        }
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: 1024,
            height: 800
        });
        var shapesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var hex = new Kinetic.Shape({
            x: 5,
            y: 10,
            fill: 'rgb(53, 74, 159)',
            // a Kinetic.Canvas renderer is passed into the drawFunc function
            drawFunc: function(canvas) {
                var context = canvas.getContext();
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(0.1, 51.9);
                context.bezierCurveTo(0.1, 43.6, 4.6, 35.8, 11.9, 31.6);
                context.lineTo(61.0, 3.3);
                context.bezierCurveTo(68.2, -0.9, 77.2, -0.9, 84.4, 3.3);
                context.lineTo(133.6, 31.6);
                context.bezierCurveTo(140.8, 35.8, 145.3, 43.6, 145.3, 52.0);
                context.lineTo(145.3, 108.7);
                context.bezierCurveTo(145.3, 117.1, 140.8, 124.8, 133.6, 129.0);
                context.lineTo(84.4, 157.4);
                context.bezierCurveTo(77.2, 161.5, 68.2, 161.5, 61.0, 157.4);
                context.lineTo(11.9, 129.0);
                context.bezierCurveTo(4.6, 124.8, 0.1, 117.0, 0.1, 108.7);
                context.lineTo(0.1, 51.9);
                context.closePath();
                canvas.fillStroke(this);
            }
        });
        var zoomIn = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
            var period = 2500;
            var duration = 250;
            zoomAmount = 1;
            var scale =frame.time / period;
            hex.setScale(frame.time / period + zoomAmount);
            if(frame.time > duration) {
                zoomIn.stop();
                this.frame.time = 0;
            }
        }, shapesLayer);
        var zoomOut = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
            var period = 2500;
            var duration = 250;
            zoomAmount = 1;
            hex.setScale(zoomAmount - frame.time / period + 0.102);
            if(frame.time > duration) {
                zoomOut.stop();
                this.frame.time = 0;
            }
        }, shapesLayer);
        hex.on('mouseover', function() {
            zoomIn.start();
            //zoomIn.stop();
        });
        hex.on('mouseleave', function() {
            zoomOut.start();
            //zoomOut.stop();
        });
        shapesLayer.add(hex);
        stage.add(shapesLayer);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can easily reuse your Hex drawing coordinates using context.translate.**

Here is an example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/J7Zce/

[image]

context.translate(x,y) will cause the next drawing to begin as if [x,y] were the [0,0] coordinate.

That way you don’t have to adjust your hex coordinates to use them at a different location.

*The method:*

- First, use context.save to save the context in its untranslated state.
- Then context.translate(165,10) moves the drawing origin to [165,10].
- Then draw your hex (using your same unaltered line/curve coordinates)
- Finally, use contex.restore to return context to its untranslated state.

This code draws your hex at [165,10] without changing any of your hex coordinates:

```
drawFunc: function(canvas) {
    var context = canvas.getContext();
    context.save();
    context.translate(165,10);
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(0.1, 51.9);
    context.bezierCurveTo(0.1, 43.6, 4.6, 35.8, 11.9, 31.6);
    context.lineTo(61.0, 3.3);
    context.bezierCurveTo(68.2, -0.9, 77.2, -0.9, 84.4, 3.3);
    context.lineTo(133.6, 31.6);
    context.bezierCurveTo(140.8, 35.8, 145.3, 43.6, 145.3, 52.0);
    context.lineTo(145.3, 108.7);
    context.bezierCurveTo(145.3, 117.1, 140.8, 124.8, 133.6, 129.0);
    context.lineTo(84.4, 157.4);
    context.bezierCurveTo(77.2, 161.5, 68.2, 161.5, 61.0, 157.4);
    context.lineTo(11.9, 129.0);
    context.bezierCurveTo(4.6, 124.8, 0.1, 117.0, 0.1, 108.7);
    context.lineTo(0.1, 51.9);
    context.closePath();
    canvas.fillStroke(this);
    context.restore();
}
```

The following code wraps your Hex in a template function so you can repeatedly call that function to create as many hexes as you need.

The zoom code is also encapsulated within the wrapper function so all hexes will be able to zoom

Here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/J7Zce/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.5.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:400px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 400
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    // use a function to create multiple hexes
    var hexes=[];
    hexes.push(makeHex(5,10,'rgb(53, 74, 159)'));
    hexes.push(makeHex(165,10,'skyblue'));
    hexes.push(makeHex(5,175,'gold'));
    hexes.push(makeHex(165,175,'MediumAquamarine'));

    // make 1 hex
    function makeHex(x,y,fill){
        var hex = new Kinetic.Shape({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            fill: fill,
            // a Kinetic.Canvas renderer is passed into the drawFunc function
            drawFunc: function(canvas) {
                var context = canvas.getContext();
                context.save();
                context.translate(x,y);
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(0.1, 51.9);
                context.bezierCurveTo(0.1, 43.6, 4.6, 35.8, 11.9, 31.6);
                context.lineTo(61.0, 3.3);
                context.bezierCurveTo(68.2, -0.9, 77.2, -0.9, 84.4, 3.3);
                context.lineTo(133.6, 31.6);
                context.bezierCurveTo(140.8, 35.8, 145.3, 43.6, 145.3, 52.0);
                context.lineTo(145.3, 108.7);
                context.bezierCurveTo(145.3, 117.1, 140.8, 124.8, 133.6, 129.0);
                context.lineTo(84.4, 157.4);
                context.bezierCurveTo(77.2, 161.5, 68.2, 161.5, 61.0, 157.4);
                context.lineTo(11.9, 129.0);
                context.bezierCurveTo(4.6, 124.8, 0.1, 117.0, 0.1, 108.7);
                context.lineTo(0.1, 51.9);
                context.closePath();
                canvas.fillStroke(this);
                context.restore();
            }
        });
        hex.on('mouseover', function() {
            this.zoomIn.start();
            //zoomIn.stop();
        });
        hex.on('mouseleave', function() {
            this.zoomOut.start();
            //zoomOut.stop();
        });
        //
        hex.zoomIn = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
                var period = 2500;
                var duration = 250;
                zoomAmount = 1;
                var scale =frame.time / period;
                hex.setScale(frame.time / period + zoomAmount);
                if(frame.time > duration) {
                    hex.zoomIn.stop();
                    this.frame.time = 0;
                }
            }, layer);
        hex.zoomOut = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
                var period = 2500;
                var duration = 250;
                zoomAmount = 1;
                hex.setScale(zoomAmount - frame.time / period + 0.102);
                if(frame.time > duration) {
                    hex.zoomOut.stop();
                    this.frame.time = 0;
                }
            }, layer);

        layer.add(hex);

        layer.draw();
    }


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use KineticJS' extend function:

`Kinetic.Util.extend(Kinetic.customShape, Kinetic.Shape)`

Example:

```
    (function() {
        Kinetic.customHex = function(config) {
            this._initHex(config);
        };

        Kinetic.MyCircle.prototype = {
            _initHex: function(config) {
                Kinetic.Shape.call(this, config);
            },
            drawFunc: function() {
            },
            customFunc : function() {
            }
        };

      Kinetic.Util.extend(Kinetic.customHex, Kinetic.Shape);
    })();
```

See the direct [KineticJS source](http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.6.0.js) and search up any Kinetic Shape (rect, circle etc..) for examples on how the `Kinetic.Shape` object is extended.